# TalkBack menu entry should beep and be present by default

Tags: settings, accessibility, talk-back

Android 4..4.2 here.

I have written about the fact that it is a shame for Android not to have a mode where you can configure the device upon first boot using your voice, which would be helpful for non-seeing users who might want to configure the device on their own using their own voice.

When this happens, TalkBack should be enabled by default.

However, it can happen to anyone to lose their vision for a fixed or extended period of time. When this happens, what the user wants out of their phone is first and foremost the ability to make phone calls and read and compose SMS messages.

Therefore, I suggest that when the power key is held down, the TalkBack entry be always present in the menu. This entry should be there as a polymorphic entry, so when the user hovers it, it beeps and reads "TalkBack", so it can easily be double tapped to be activated. That is, this entry works with TalkBack enabled.

This should raise blindness awareness.

If the user still has vision and doesn't want this entry because the beep bothers them, they should be able to reconfigure an alternative such as power plus double home tap toggled TalkBack (unlike double home tap that brings up the still clumsy, actually imo unusable by non-seeing people, Google now).

At least, is there currently a menu setting where I can change this for the time being, just in case I lose my vision again...

but this is not what I am asking. I would like to know how and when Android developers will address the entire issue, and also whether this is the right place to address the issue, or whether there is a separate forum for seeing users who want to support blind accessibility on Android in all of its device forms.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I will say I am sorry this does seem to be a thing with developers.  Not keeping those user's with impairments in mind when designing things, and they only seem to make those adjustments after users inform them that while it is nice to have accessibility if they can't get to it EASILY it's uselss.  Can't believe Android did not have this setting from day 1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a feature request description, not a question that can be answered by a community of users.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this has been handled I believe.  Here is the Official Info from the page I will link below this.

"Option 1: Turn on TalkBack when you first turn on your device
This option is available for devices running Android 4.0 and above. Learn how to check your Android version.

When you first turn on your Android device, you can enable TalkBack from the initial setup screen.

If possible, keep headphones handy so that you can plug them in when it's time to enter any passwords, such as your WiFi password. By default, key echo is only turned on if headphones are plugged into your device. You can change this setting later in your Android device settings.

Devices running Android 4.1 and above: Press and hold two fingers on the setup screen. When your device recognizes this gesture, TalkBack is enabled and a tutorial begins.
Devices running Android 4.0: Use your finger to draw a closed rectangle on the setup screen. When your device recognizes this gesture, you'll hear a beep."

https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6007100?hl=en&ref_topic=3529932